# Assets (P&T) No thumbnail for Admin group

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, thumbnails

My admins can upload images to Assets field.  They even see the thumbnail before saving. After saving though, the thumbnail does not display.  This is a site-wide issue.  I have updated the index. It also seems to be removing the image completely if it is saved again.

Assets 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the system/expressionengine/cache folder is writable. Also, consider updating Assets as you have a much older version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The cache folder and the cache/assets folder is set to 777. I also updated Assets to the latest version.  I'm still having this problem.  I did however notice something strange when I went to update the index.  There are folders showing that do not exist.  E.g.  Images [4] , uploads [4]  Could this be related to the permissions issue?

Comment: I'm still really stuck on this.  I have multisite manager installed. The upload directories such as Images [4] belong to the other site. Not sure if it makes much of a difference. I also uninstalled and the re-installed assets, still with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a problem with a server path on one of the upload directories.